# Does wildfly-maven-plugin support deploying jBPM artifacts to KIE workbench

Tags: java, maven, deployment, wildfly, kie

As we know, it's very handy to use wildfly-maven-plugin to deploy jfs or other artifacts to wildfly. Unfortunately, deploying jBPM artifacts to wildfly manually is tedious and error-prone. As far as I know there are two ways to deploy an artifact to KIE ([JBPM 6.2. How to deploy a workflow directly from Eclipse instead of KIE workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130841/jbpm-6-2-how-to-deploy-a-workflow-directly-from-eclipse-instead-of-kie-workbenc) ),

1. KIE workbench->Deploy->Process Deployments
2. Call rest deployment API.

Neither of them are satisfied for me. What I am pursuing is as simple as

```
mvn wildfly:deploy
```

I tried this, it returns no error, but there's no process available in KIE.

Comment: The wildfly plugin is for managing wildfly, not for jBPM/KIE

Comment: @JohnAment, I understand this's not ganno work. What I'm seeking is a similar way (maven plugin) to easily deploy jBPM process.